# How can I check which values in an array are in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array of values that I want to check to see if it is in the database already. This array can grow upto 100 elements. What's the best way to check it? Should I pull all the table data and then check against it? Should/Can I do this in 1 SQL statement? If so, how? I'm using PHP.

Edit:

I should add that I am checking to see which ones are in the database so then I can add the ones that aren't in there. Maybe there's a better solution than what I was thinking.

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: How silly of me to forget to mention! PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM tablename WHERE name IN ('".implode("','", $array_of_names)."')";
```

Comment: This returns the ones that are in the database. How can I have it tell me which ones aren't? Because I'm trying to insert only the new ones.

Comment: Use [`array_diff()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to compare the two arrays. The ones remaining aren't in your database.

Comment: I think putting `NOT` in front of `IN` would just select all the rows where any of the `('...')` values aren't in not in a row right? I wanted to know which ones in my array are not in the database already? or Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Thanks John Conde! Pronounced as `Con-day`?

Comment: Con-dee. Surprisingly some people think it's sounds like candy. I think they're brain dead. :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a statement dynamically like this:

```
select *
from table
where value in (3, 5, 8, 12, 17, (etc))
```

produce the list of values from the array in whatever language you are using.